# Difficulty in solving calculus of variation problem.

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I am having difficulty setting $F(x,y_1,y_2,y_1^{'},y_2^{'})$ of the following question. any help will be appreciated.

$$v(y_1,y_2)=\displaystyle\int_{0} ^ {1}(y_1+y_2)dx$$   $$\ y_1(0)=y_2(0)=0$$ 
$$ y_1(1)=1 ,\ y_2(1)=-3 $$  $$\displaystyle \int_0^1 y_1{'} y_2{'}dx=0. $$

Should I write $F(x,y_1,y_2,y_1^{'},y_2^{'})=y_1+y_2+\lambda_1 \lambda_2y_1{'} y_2{'}?$

Answer to the given problem is $$y_1=3x^2-2x , y_2=3x^2-6x $$ $$y_1=-3x^2+4x , y_2=-3x^2  $$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Use the [Lagrange multiplier method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). Define functional
   $$S[y_1,y_2,\lambda] ~:=~ \int_0^1 \! \mathrm{d}x~\{y_1(x)+y_2(x)\} +\lambda  \int_0^1 \! \mathrm{d}x~y_1^{\prime}(x) y_2^{\prime}(x).\tag{1}$$
2. The [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) become
   $$ \lambda y_i^{\prime\prime}(x)~=~1, \qquad i~\in~\{1,2\}.\tag{2}$$
3. Clearly $\lambda\neq 0$. Define the reciprocal $\mu:=\lambda^{-1}$ for later convenience.
4. The solution to EL eqs. (2) with boundary conditions 
   $$y_i(0)~=~0, \qquad i~\in~\{1,2\},\tag{3}$$
   is
   $$y_i(x)~=~\frac{\mu}{2}x^2 + a_i x, \qquad i~\in~\{1,2\},\tag{4}$$
   where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are integration constants.
5. The remaining boundary condition
   $$ y_1(1)~=~1\qquad\text{and}\qquad y_2(1)~=~-3\tag{5} $$
   leads to 
   $$ a_1~=~1-  \frac{\mu}{2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad a_2~=~-3-  \frac{\mu}{2}.\tag{6}$$
6. The constraint 
   $$0~=~\int_0^1 \! \mathrm{d}x~y_1^{\prime}(x) y_2^{\prime}(x)
   ~=~\int_0^1 \! \mathrm{d}x~ (\mu x + a_1)(\mu x + a_2)
   ~=~\frac{\mu^2}{3}+ \mu\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}+a_1a_2$$ 
   $$ ~=~\frac{\mu^2}{3}-\mu\left(1+\frac{\mu}{2}\right)-\left(1-\frac{\mu}{2}\right)\left(3+\frac{\mu}{2}\right) ~=~\frac{\mu^2}{12}-3\tag{7}$$ 
   becomes a quadratic equation in $\mu$, with solution
   $$ \mu~=~\pm 6,\tag{8}$$ 
   in agreement with OP's announced solution.